# How can I access the URLs of the all the HTML files I have uploaded to my website on 000webhost

Tags: html, url

**Summary:**
I am a beginner to HTML and need to work out the URLs (or how to make them) of files I have added to 000webhost. I have been given the URL of my index file, and can access it easily, but the links I have placed in it do not work, as I cannot find/don't have the URL of the links (though I do have the code). Is there a way of finding/making a URL for each of the files I have added to my 000webhost project?

So I'm a beginner to HTML and after making a basic website (including links to other pages I have created)I have decided to try and upload it to the internet. I watched a couple YouTube videos on how I should do so and ended up using  htmlsave.net . I copy and pasted my code in, changing all my links from places om my desktop to the URLs provided by the website, and everything worked. However, since I had not paid money for a membership I quickly reached my limit on how many pages I could reach. Because of this, I decided to use another(free) web host that would not limit me on how many web pages I could add to a website.

After some research I settled on 000webhost. Everything started off smoothly, I created the project, added my files and got my index file up and running. However, from my index page (which I could now access on the internet), I could not use the links inside it, as they were still still linked to locations on my computer.

Therefore, I opened the code to edit it, but then quickly realized I did not know the new URL of all the files(excluding the index file (named index.html) which 000webhost **had** provided me as stated earlier) I had added to my 000webhost project.

So after looking around on google and stack overflow I have not been able to find a solution on how to find out the new URL given to the files I have added to 000webhost.

(Apologies for any incorrect use of terminology, as stated I am extremely new to HTML)

Comment: If the url for your index file is `url/index.html` other files are found under `url/otherfile.html` or, if they are in a different folder, `url/folder/otherfile.html`

Comment: When I type in the website name (www.url.com), the index page is opened. However, on the address at the top of the browser it is still url, without the /index.html. I did try typing the url/index but there was an error. Thanks for the reply though and I will take a further look into trying to type in different urls

Comment: `index.html` is often not shown. But your other files should be accesible by `www.yourdomain/filename.html` or `www.yourdomain/folder/filename.html`. [here's some basic knowledge](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL)

Comment: Thank you so much! After reading the website and fiddling around a bit with the URL I managed to work out how to find each file I added. 
Also, do I need to write the answer to my question here? Or should I leave it because people can read the comments